# How can I search privately in Chrome while also logged into my Google acount?

Tags: google-search, google-account, privacy

I access both Gmail and Google Search while logged in to my Google account (Chrome browser), but I don't want the searches associated with my account.

I've tried Google Search alternatives, like DuckDuckGo, but I really prefer Google.

I'm aware I could perform my searches in a separate "incognito mode" window or a completely different web browser, but I am looking for a solution that uses the existing browser window.

How can I use Google Search privately while logged in to my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't an answer my own question about Google Chrome itself, but I have achieved what I wanted using Firefox and the [**Google Container** addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-container/) and enabling "Ignore search pages" for that addon's options.

[image: Tick the "Ignore search pages" in the Google Container options]

This allows me to log out of Google when searching...

[image: Partial screenshot of google search showing that I am logged out]

But when accessing Gmail or Calendar etc the container is used and my login is retained and the Google Container badge appears...

[image: Partial screenshot of Gmail showing that I am logged in, with a badge showing the Google Container is active]

Note that there are known issues working with other containers that the [addon description](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-container/) covers.

Comment: Solution for Chrome: Set [Startpage as default search engine](https://support.startpage.com/hc/en-us/articles/5319991439380-Set-Startpage-as-default-search-engine-in-Chromium) Startpage uses search results from Google, for which it pays, and will integrate seamlessly as Chrome's default search provider. A near-perfect solution.

Answer (score 3):

There may be others, but https://disconnect.me/search is a well known tool to use popular search engines (including Google) without being tracked by the search provider (or the tool provider).

Comment: June 2023::   **No longer relevant:**
 [disconnect.me/search](https://disconnect.me/search) now uses DuckDuckGo exclusively.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/bangs?q=!google allows websearch via DDG for Google (and other site) results.

Comment: Turns out that DuckDuckGo "bangs" service currently redirects to other sites rather than proxies their results, so it's not a good solution. This answer is no longer the best answer. But many things have changed over the years since the original question, including quality of Google and DuckDuckGo results. The question (unlogged Google search results in Chrome while logged in to Google, without using incognito) may be too constrained to have a good answer.

Comment: I haven't used Startpage for years, and don't have Chrome or Chromium, so can't test it. Community is welcome to edit the answer, un-accept it, or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: I'll give it some thought. ty

Answer (score 2):

## Browse Google without being logged in while still logged into Gmail

To use Google, aka Google Search, without being logged in while you are logged in Gmail, use one of the following:

1: Two different web browsers
2: Use two different web browser profiles
3: Use two windows of the same web browser, one in regular navigation mode and the other in private navigation mode <sup>1</sup>

The above is because Google Inc. now use a only one login for most of their web services, so once you sign in almost any Google web service you will be logged in most the the others.

Notes:
1 : In Google Chrome the private navigation mode is called *incognito mode*.

## References

- [Create a Google account - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?hl=en)